# Integration/differentiation through the FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, numerical-methods

I'm trying to understand how to perform an integration or differentiation of an FFT using MATLAB. However, I think I'm doing something wrong somewhere and would like to know what I'm missing...

Here's an example of an FFT integration that, to the best of my knowledge, should work but doesn't.

```
clc; clear all; close all;

Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
L = 1500;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector

f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;

omega = 2*pi.*f;
```

`S` is the time signal we are going to operate the FFT on, and `dS` is its derivative. We're going to apply an FFT to `dS`, and try to integrate that transform to get the same result as `S`.

```
S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);

dS = 70*pi*cos(2*pi*50*t) + 140*pi*cos(2*pi*120*t);

P2 = fft(S);
Y = P2(1:L/2+1);

c = fft(dS);
dm = c(1:L/2+1);
```

From what I found online, to integrate an FFT, you need to multiply each FFT value by the corresponding `omega*1i`. I'm assuming each point on the FFT result correspond to the values of my frequency vector `f`.

```
for z = 1:length(f)
    dm(z) = dm(z)./(1i*omega(z));
end

figure
semilogy(f,abs(Y),'b'); hold on
semilogy(f,abs(dm),'r');
```

We can see on the plot that both curves don't match: the FFT of the initial time signal `S` is different from the integral of the FFT of the differentiated time signal `dS`.

[image: plot result from code above]

Comment: How do you get 140 in the derivative of the second term? You probably mistyped the correct 240=2*120.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between your two plots is in the noise. Because you use a logarithmic y axis, the noise gets blown up and looks important. Pay attention to the magnitudes when comparing. Anything about 10<sup>15</sup> times smaller than the peak value should be ignored. This is the precision of the floating-point numbers used.

The relevant part of these frequency spectra is the two peaks. And the difference there between the sine and cosine is the phase. But you are plotting the magnitude, so the function and its derivative will look the same. Plot the phase also! (but only where the magnitude is above the noise level).